# (In Matlab) How would I switch to another working directory in the middle of a for loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, directory

Currently, I have data in two separate folders (say folder A and folder B).

I have a for loop code which analyses the relevant variables for each participant. The beginning portion of my for loop runs through the variables found in data contained in folder A; however, I would like to include variables from the data in folder B at the end of my for loop.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

I've tried adding a line to change the directory once the loop reaches the portion of the loop for extracting the variables from folder B. But this causes a

> Error using load' 'X file is not found in the current folder.

Now I have placed both directories at the beginning of my script and tried loading them both before the loop starts.

```matlab
cd('folderAPath')
addpath('folderBPath')
filesA = dir(filenameA) 
filesB = dir(filenameB)
```

When trying to use the `load`() function for files `A` and `B`, the files from folder `B` do not load into my workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the current working folder before calling the dir (...) command to point to the correct folder.

```
cd('folderAPath')
filesA = dir(filenameA)
cd('folderBPath') 
filesB = dir(filenameB)
```

Comment: This assumes that `folderB` is inside `folderA`. If that is not the case, change the second `cd` to `cd('../folderBPath')`.

Comment: This can be handled by making 'folderAPath' and 'folderBPath' the complete path of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Matlab cannot locate the files in folder B.

Say your directory tree is something like this:

```
--root_folder
  --folderA
  --folderB
```

If you change directory (cd) to folderA, folderB is not visible if you don't provide the entire path (from root folder).

One of these approaches will solve your problem:

1. Provide the entire path (from root folder) to the load function
2. cd to folder B and load your data

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to load the files in folderB when folderB isn't on your filepath.

for example if the path to the files are as follows:

`C:/Users/.../.../MATLAB/folderA`

`C:/Users/.../.../MATLAB/folderB`

have the following above and outside of your loop:

```
addpath('C:/Users/.../.../MATLAB/folderA');
addpath('C:/Users/.../.../MATLAB/folderB');
```

Then just do something like the following pseudocode:

```
numFilesA = number of files in folder A
numFilesB = number of files in folder B
totalFiles = numFilesA + numFilesB

for i in totalFiles
    if i <= numFilesA   
       load folderA/file(i)
    else % we've read all the files in folderA
       load folderB/file(i-numFilesA) % because we want to load from index 1 of the new folder
    % and do whatever other stuff you want to do in here
    end 
end
```